# Extract time from a DateTime string on xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xslt-1.0, extract

I've got an xml file full of this nodes:

```
<FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2014-05-02T14:24:00" ArrivalDateTime="2014-05-02T15:42:00"/>
<FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2014-05-02T16:24:00" ArrivalDateTime="2014-05-02T17:42:00"/>
```

And i need to extract just the time of the @DepartureDateTime and @ArrivalDateTime in a html output. So far, i made a xsl:for-each and a xsl:value-of that returns the full string, but i tried using the fn:hours-from-dateTime and it doesn't work. Either i'm doing something wrong, or it only works in 2.0.
How can i get just the time from this string?

This is my code:

```
<table>
        <xsl:for-each select="FlightSegment">
            <tr>
                <td>
                  Departure:
                </td>
                <td>
                   <fn:hours-from-dateTime(xsl:value-of select="@DepartureDateTime")/>:<fn:minutes-from-dateTime(xsl:value-of select="@DepartureDateTime")/>:<fn:seconds-from-dateTime(xsl:value-of select="@DepartureDateTime")/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   Arrival:
                </td>
                <td>
                   <fn:hours-from-dateTime(xsl:value-of select="@ArrivalDateTime")/>:<fn:minutes-from-dateTime(xsl:value-of select="@ArrivalDateTime")/>:<fn:seconds-from-dateTime(xsl:value-of select="@ArrivalDateTime")/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you see a function described as `fn:anything` then it is almost certainly 2.0-only.  The only functions available by default in XPath 1.0 are [these ones](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib), essentially the functions to extract information from nodes (`namespace-uri`, `local-name`, etc.), some basic string manipulation (no regular expressions!) and a few numeric functions like `sum` and `round`.  And they don't take a namespace prefix - XPath 1.0 knows nothing about the `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions` namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For extracting dates and time from the following:

```
<Root>
<myDate>2014-05-01T07:24:00</myDate>
</Root>
```

I use the following functions to get the data or convert to other formats:

```
<p>
Extract just the date: <br />
<xsl:value-of select="substring(/Root/myDate, 1, 10)" />
</p>

<p>
Extract just the time: <br />
<xsl:value-of select="substring(/Root/myDate, 12, 5)" />
</p>

<p>Convert to Short date format dd-MM-yyyy: <br />
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(/Root/myDate, 9, 2), '-', substring(/Root/myDate, 6, 2), '-', substring(/Root/myDate, 1, 4))" />
</p>
```

I have had the need to use the full month name in a date string, so use lookups with the following stylesheet. Although I have never managed to get the substring function for the month value to work within the [ ] in the lookup xpath, it has never had an impact on the performance on the results i have produced by using a variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:lookup="http://any.com/lookup" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:decimal-format name="NN" NaN="-" />
    <lookup:Months>
        <Month index="01" string="January" />
        <Month index="02" string="February" />
        <Month index="03" string="March" />
        <Month index="04" string="April" />
        <Month index="05" string="May" />
        <Month index="06" string="June" />
        <Month index="07" string="July" />
        <Month index="08" string="August" />
        <Month index="09" string="September" />
        <Month index="10" string="October" />
        <Month index="11" string="November" />
        <Month index="12" string="December" />
    </lookup:Months>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>
                    Convert to Long date format dd-MMM-yyyy: <br />
                    <xsl:variable name="myMonth" select="substring(/Root/myDate, 6, 2)" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(/Root/myDate, 9, 2), ' ', document('')/*/lookup:Months/Month[@index=$myMonth]/@string, ' ',  substring(/Root/myDate, 1, 4))" />
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Now i'll be able to move on to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, this will give you a quick result:

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@DepartureDateTime, 'T')"/>
</td>
```

If you place that in a variable you can then use `substring` functions to extract the individual components of the time, if you need to.

Comment: "*I'm not sure it will work on all XSLT 1.0 processors.*" Which XSLT 1.0 processor does it work on?

Comment: Probably none :) A decade ago I wrote a few schema-aware extensions for XSLT 1.0 in Java. I used them a couple of times and never more.

Comment: Well, XSLT 1.0 does not support XML schema and it says so expressly. P.S. I am not really happy with your edit leaving my comment up in the air...

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't know how to fix it in a way to avoid that problem. I made it community wiki.